# Comparing 0x00000000 with 0xFFFFFFFF in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to sort through a list of 32-bit numbers using MIPS assembler and [xspim](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/xspim.pdf). I've been stepping trough my code to see what fails and noticed that when comparing 0x00000000 with 0xFFFFFFFF it doesn't compare these numbers as it should. At the point where the program fails I got 0x00000000 in $t3 and 0xFFFFFFFF in $t4 and it looks like this:

`bge $t3,$t4,lol` #So if `t3` is greater than or equal I should jump forward else continue. Now the problem is that the program jumps even though `t3` is smaller.

Comment: Perhaps it interprets 0xffffffff as -1 (2-complement)?

Comment: I skipped my sorting code and just printed the numbers and some of them where negative. How do I get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `0xffffffff` is interpreted as `-1`, i.e., in 2-complement.

There are specific instructions to deal with numbers as if they were unsigned. Use these instructions. (Compare for instance `bgt` and `bgtu` where `u` stands for unsigned.)